# Technique to embed photos in a Video

Tags: php, flash, video

Currently, I'm going to make a website that allows people to upload their photos and embed them in a video. The photo then appears in the video with many effects, like scaling, positioning, etc...
One example site is http://www.onetruemedia.com/

I would like to ask how to create a video that can achieve that functionality. I thought of creating a video in Adobe Flash, then loading the image dynamically.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg-PHP http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Videos are basically images(frames) which run based on per second. What ffmpeg will let you do is take the video as input divide it in various images. Now you can either add an image or manipulate any image you got from ffmpeg and than regenerate the video again.

The documentation will help you understand how this can be achieved.